# problems after installation in a windows 8 preinstalled computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

When i am installing ubuntu 13.10 it did not find any operating system in my computer,so i did the installation using something else by creating (ext4 \ for 30gb),(ext4 \boot for 200mb)and(swap area for 3gb).

It worked properly twice ,until i boot windows 8 again.

After booting windows 8 once i cant find a menu giving options to choose operating system.

It simply starts running  windows automatically!!

I have read many similar questions and the corresponding answers from people in this forum, but till now I haven't found a solution.

Could someone help me on this subject?

Thanks in advance!

specifications - vaio e series,
4gb ram, intel i3, 500gb hdd.

Comment: did you try boot-repair?

Comment: yes i tried it after your suggestion , this did help for my problem.